# Should i use 23:59:59 or 00:00:00 for 12 AM in 24 hours time format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format, timespan

When I search about maximum time. people always answering that from VS debugger. which is 23:59:59.9999999

As I need 12 AM in 24 formats. I guess it will be 00:00:00 but...
C# .NET assume the following:

```
var xx = DateTime.MaxValue.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
```

When debugging previous it will print **23:59:59.9999999**

> What should I use? does it matter? what's the difference?
>
> Should use **00:00:00**  ? or **23:59:59.9999999** Specially when
>   saving **Time** in SQL-Server.

The big problem or I mean un-good behavior for end-user when you convert 24 formats to 12 Hour format via **hh:mm:ss**   it will show `11:59:59 PM` **it will be ugly isn't it?** it should be `12:00:00 AM.`

After All, **Obsidian Age** answered this well depending on the use case.

Comment: I guess that there is no 12 pm. Like the is no 24:00. We have `02.12 23:59:59.9999999` and after one micro-second we have `03.12 00:00:00.00000000`. The analogy for weeks will be: What is 8 day of the week?

Comment: @BasilKosovan You would guess wrong, they even use 12:15 PM. Imagine using a zero. And yes, for midnight it would be 12 AM, the day start :)

Comment: It's 12AM not 12PM you are talking about. And 12AM is 00:00:00 in 24 hour format.

Comment: There is a rare - but not excluded - possibility of a minute having 61 seconds. Apparently this is what some do to deal with leap seconds. Because that thing was not yet driving enough people borderline insane: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: I would [avoid using 12 AM and 12 PM altogether to prevent confusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight) -- the time you're talking about is midnight. Where possible, do not rely on "the last possible time in the day" at all, because (especially when using `DATETIME`, which has limited accuracy) you can run into problems representing this value, or having it rounded. Storing that many 9s needs a `TIME(7)`, which is wasteful if you don't actually need that much precision.

Comment: @Christopher A minute almost always has 60 seconds. And "dirving" should probably be "driving" in above comment.

Comment: The strange thing when I debugging with my PC clock it shows 00:00:00, but `DateTime.MaxValue` is 23:59:59. I mean the end of the day which is 12 AM? what's wrong with that. what should I use? I mean correctly use.

Comment: This question confuses me, lunch time is 12pm, represented as 12:00:00 in a 24hr clock, while midnight is 12am, represented as  00:00:00 in a 24hr clock.

Comment: so what is 23:59:59 ??

Comment: 23:59:59 is 11:59:59 PM, which is followed immediately by 12:00 AM. You might think 12:00 PM would be close to 11:59 PM, but you'd be wrong. The 24-hour clock has its own issues, but at least it avoids this.

Comment: What is even being asked here? It seems to be about midnight or the second just before, but then it claims that's equal to `12:00:00 PM`, which is wrong.  It asks about formats with both fractional and whole seconds. It seems to be about the format displayed to the end user, but then adds "Specially when saving Time in SQL-Server", to which formatting wouldn't apply. If you're displaying time to the second and the time is `11:59:59 PM` then just display that; why would you change it to something else? Does `11:59:58 PM` get changed, too, or where's the threshold? Why is `11:59:59 PM` "ugly"?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on perspective:

```
var xx = DateTime.MaxValue.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
var xy = DateTime.MinValue.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff");
```

Gives

> 23:59:59.9999999
>
> 00:00:00.0000000

So, one is the end of the day and the other is the beginning of the day.

There's an interesting novel called 'The time between midnight'

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.MaxValue` is exactly that - the *maximum* value that `DateTime` can represent; that is to say, the 'last' point in a day. Conversely, the `.Date` property makes use of `00:00:00` by default, as it has no notion of time (unless specified).

If you have an event that occurs at exactly midnight, I would recommend storing it as `00:00:00`, as the event occurs at *midnight*, and you want to accurately represent that.

Ultimately, it really depends on your desired use case as to which one you want to use. Do you want to state that the event occurs on day 1's evening, or day 2's beginning? That is what it boils down to, although in the vast majority of cases such a delineation makes no difference. In this case you would want to opt for both the accuracy and 'ease' of `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

programmatically speaking, you can do both. the only difference between them (in code) is this :

```
 // using 00:00:00 will require you to add 1 day to the end date in order to count as full day
 if(time >= "2019-12-03 00:00:00" && time < "2019-12-04 00:00:00")

//using 23:59:59 will not require you to add 1 day to the end date.
 if(time >= "2019-12-03 00:00:00" && time <= "2019-12-03 23:59:59")
```

so, basically, if you use `23:59:59` there is a one second off the grid, if any record has been stored in this second, it'll not be included in the results. while the second one will include it.

Which one to use ? surely the `00:00:00` if you want to be more precise, however, I've not seen any difference in the results in my projects as I've used both of them in different projects. But I'm sure there are some projects needs to include every micro second as this microsecond could change the result's curve (such as analytics or deep learning ..etc).

In SQL Server, don't save the time as string, save it with the correct datatype (DateTime, TimeSpan ..etc). SQL Server will reads the time perfectly fine when you pass a correspond time datatype from your application.

Comment: but IDK why you do string comparison with timespan? can you give real-example in c#

Comment: When comparing from 00:00 to 00:00, the range should be treated as half-open (inclusive at the front, exclusive at the end).  I edited your answer to use `<` instead of `<=` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- The maximum value that a `DateTime` in C# can represent is `9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999`.  In SQL Server, this corresponds to a `datetime2`, which has the same maximum value.
- The `time` type in SQL Server also has a maximum value of `23:59:59.9999999` (though note that a C# `TimeSpan` can be much larger because it primarily represents duration instead of time of day).
- If you are storing just a time range using the `time` type, you'll need that `23:59:59.9999999` value for the end of the day.  You can get this quickly in C# with `DateTime.MaxValue.TimeOfDay`.  Indeed it will be one tick less than a true `24:00`.
- There are 7 decimals of nines because that is the precision offered by the data type.  If you choose a lower precision, there is some small (but not impossible) chance that a given value could fall after it.  Thus when you use this technique, always align the nines with the full precision of the data type.  (Don't just subtract one second or one millisecond.)
- When calculating the difference of a datetime range such as `2020-01-01 00:00` to `2020-01-01 01:00`, one can simply subtract the two values to get the result (1 hour in this case).  However, when using `23:59:59.99999999`, one has to account for the missing tick.  This can get messy, and such there is a significant advantage to using `00:00` instead.
- As you pointed out, when displaying `23:59:59.9999999` to an end user, you may have to write your own logic to format it as `24:00` or as `"end of day"`, etc.
- When comparing datetime ranges, you'll want to use a different operator for the end comparison:

  - If you use `23:59:59.9999999`, use a fully-inclusive range comparison: `a <= now && b >= now`
  - If you use `00:00`, use a *half-open* range comparison - inclusive at the start, exclusive at the end: `a <= now && b > now`
- When comparing time-only ranges (i.e. timspan types), the same logic applies, but one also has to consider time ranges that span over midnight:

  - If you use `23:59:59.9999999`:

    ```
    if (a < b)
        result = a <= now && b >= now;
    else
        result = a <= now || b >= now;
    ```
  - If you use `00:00`:

    ```
    if (a < b)
        result = a <= now && b > now;
    else
        result = a <= now || b > now;
    ```

In summary, it is generally simpler to work with `00:00` values instead of `23:59:59.9999999` values, and thus you should prefer `00:00`.  If you find the need to use `23:59:59.9999999`, you should be aware of the coding changes required.